# Use PS1 setting to set different terminal background color over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, ps1

I want to use the PS1 setting in my .bashrc file to change the color of the terminal based on whether I'm on my local machine or using ssh.

My current .bashrc file on both my local machine and the ssh server is (the default):
`PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '`

I've tried adding `"\e[40m"` to the end, but only changes part of the background of the terminal, leaving a black bar in the middle

How would I go about changing the PS1 setting to, say, my local terminal is dark blue and the ssh terminal is dark gray?

Thanks!

Comment: The escape codes only change the color used for the background of subsequently printed characters, not the entire background of your terminal window. That is handled by your terminal emulator, not the shell.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity, doesn't that remote machine set its own `PS1` value which means however you set your prompt locally, that remote machine will override it?

One way around this is to setup a function to replace your actual `ssh` command. Have that function set the color of your terminal, and then run the actual `ssh` command:

```
function ssh_function
{
    printf "\e[40m\e[37m"    # Grey on black
    clear
    \ssh $@ || read           # Actual ssh command
    printf "\e[0m"           # Reset terminal
    clear
}
```

Now, create an alias:

```
alias ssh="ssh_function"
```

Now, when you run `ssh`, it will run your `ssh_function` which sets the screen color before executing `ssh` and then resets your screen colors once out of `ssh`. The `clear` is to clear your terminal, so you get a constant color. Otherwise, it merely resets the color at your prompt.

And then hope that the remote `PS1` environment variable doesn't reset the terminal color on you.

Comment: Why do you need an alias _and_ a function? wouldn't the function `ssh` alone work? Also, you very likely forgot to pass the arguments of the function to the command `ssh`: `command ssh "$@"`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to pass the `ssh` parameters. You need a different name for the function because in some versions of Bash `\ssh` calls the function called `ssh` and not the command itself. When you alias, the alias calls the function, and `\ssh` is the unaliased name. Thus, you need both a function and an alias.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I also did a bit of error checking when I run the ssh command incase you give it a bad remote name. Otherwise, the terminal flashes, and you don't see the error message.

Comment: Would be better to pass the arguments as `"$@"` instead of `$*`. To ensure that the _command_ `ssh` is invoked, prepend the builtin `command` like so: `command ssh "$@"`.

Comment: Oh, and you definitely don't want to _pipe_ `ssh` through `read`. You want `command ssh "$@" || read`.

Comment: I'll fix these issues.

Comment: Right now, using different a different PS1 on the server and my local machine correctly switches between different layouts. The question is just getting the PS1 string right.

Comment: Nicely done. Maybe a link for further reading? e.g.
http://www.andrewnoske.com/wiki/Unix_-_ANSI_colors